# What are the ideal widths a website should be designed for on a phone/tablet/computer?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, adaptive-content

What are the ideal/typical widths that an [adaptive/responsive](http://www.zeldman.com/2011/07/06/responsive-design-i-dont-think-that-word-means-what-you-think-it-means/) website should be designed for in order to accomodate the most devices possible?

Comment: this screen size has a name called "viewport".
you just need to search viewport size of the device and write responsive web design according to this resolution.

Comment: most people set it 480 width (or less) to active mobile web design layout, but this is somewhat outdated.  There is a smartphone by HTC => HTC Evo 3D  (viewport is 540 width).  So using 540 width as a guideline for responsive web design is the better choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below are the sizes I like to design for; not all of these may be ideal for your needs, however I find this tend to provide the cater to the most common configurations of devices out there. When I refer to device width, it is in "[device independent pixels](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)" :P

**1024px**

This is the typical device width of 1:1 scale tablet in landscape mode, which also lends itself well to larger computer monitors.

- [iPad Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP580) *Note: iPad with Retina display still maintains a device width in the browser of 1024px in landscape, and 768px in portrait*
- [Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples)

**1023-980px**

This is the default viewport width for iOS devices (which is supposed to represent the "average" website width), which also lends itself well to average sized computer monitors.

- [iOS Developer Library: Configuring the Viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26)

**979-768px**

This is the device width of an Apple iPad in portrait mode. *Note: Many 16:9 Android tablets have a device width of 720px: [Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples)*

- [iPad Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP580) *Note: iPad with Retina display still maintains a device width in the browser of 1024px in landscape, and 768px in portrait*

**767-480px**

This is the typical device width of 1:1 scale phone in landscape mode.

- [iOS Developer Library: Layout and Metrics on iPhone and iPod touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW24)
- [Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples)
- [Blackberry Development Guide: Developing applications for different screen sizes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927122913/http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Developing_apps_for_different_screen_sizes_1579421_11.jsp)
- [MSDN Blogs: The IE Mobile Viewport on Windows Phone 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/iemobile/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7)

**480-320px**

This is the typical device width of 1:1 scale phone in portrait mode.

- [iOS Developer Library: Layout and Metrics on iPhone and iPod touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW24)
- [Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples)
- [Blackberry Development Guide: Developing applications for different screen sizes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927122913/http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Developing_apps_for_different_screen_sizes_1579421_11.jsp)

Answer (score 4):

I design for 320px wide and up.  You shouldn't design for a specific set of device sizes because the range of sizes is continuously increasing - a comprehensive list of device sizes isn't comprehensive for very long.

The current trend is to design breakpoints with concern for content, not device widths, and I think this approach will work well going forward, I don't see it obsolescing any time soon.

Some articles:

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/determining-breakpoints-responsive-design

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/setting-breakpoints-in-responsive-design

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/24/beyond-common-media-query-breakpoints/